# Flash Accordion and Image Sizing

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I've been surfing the net for some cool stuff.. so I discovered this amazing (I think so) Grid Accordion from EVANTO. here's the link: http://0.s3.envato.com/files/1374064/index.html

So lately I've been experimenting some stuff with Flex 4 and AS.

Maybe someone has seen or knows how to build something like that with controllable column numbers, width and images that might be using XML.

the main thing is how to accomplish such an effect?

P.S.

I've developed an Image Slider using Flash Builder 4.5

The problem is that when I included that in HTML page when someone performs ZOOM with CTRL+ Mouse wheel in a browser, the DIV that holds my SWF file and SWF file itself increases in size but the image itself that is inside my slider still remains of the same size.. How to fix it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Could you contact the author of the Grid Accordion and ask for an AS3 version? Or if the code is available for use then you could convert it. In Flex 4 Spark you would start with a List or DataGroup to contain the items and create a custom Layout for it. You can find examples online and use the TileLayout or VerticalLayout as a starting point.